# Handling JSON flat file in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

A bit of a soft and hard question: so I have a JSON flat file that looks something like this:

```
{
 "name":
  {
    "key": "value",
    "key": "value"
  },
 "another":
  {
    "key": "value",
    "key": "value"
  },
 "yet-another":
  {
    "key": "value",
    "key": "value"
  }
}
```

What I need to do is get these key values and present them to the user as a choice. When a choice is made ('name', 'another'), this choice gets inserted into a database column.

I've thought about making a new table and inserting this file in that table, and doing autocompleting text searches on the name. How can this be done, and is it the best approach ? Another way would be to store the file in the rails directory and loading it manually when needed, but I'm not sure which choice is faster and-or structurally sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly keep the values in a JSON, but most people would expect that in a view/helper or as a model so I would not recommend it. The things I would think about are:

- Are these values prone to change at some point, or will they ever have any more logic needed around them? If so, they probably warrant a model within your DB.
- If you feel these values are more view-y (as in, they really have no logic and this is just a way of having these values somewhere to render them) then they are a good candidate for living as a data structure in your view or a helper.

In specific, in your scenario it looks like you are using them for some other reason than just rendering out views - so making a model out of these will enable you to make reports and give you other functionality for free. Then again, it's difficult to say without the full story. Hope this helps.

EDIT:

An example of what something 'static' would look like in a view:

```
  <% completion_style_icons = {
    'AllSeason' => 'fa-check',
    'Winter'    => 'fa-asterisk',
    'FourSeason'=> 'fa-th-large',
    'Grid'      => 'fa-th'
  } %>
```

Comment: These values will never change. They are essentially like a list of un-changing cooking recipes, that just need to be displayed. What exactly do you mean by 'living as a data structure', parsing the json file as a variable in the controller ?

Comment: Added an example of what I mean, that would be used within your views.
 It's not pretty but when you feel you don't need a full-fledged model it makes sense to keep things only concerning a view within the template.

Comment: Here's the thing, there's at least a thousand blocks like the JSON in the question. I'm thinking the most sensible thing is using an autocomplete gem, so when the user begins to type in the text box, what they want shows up. Is making a database model the best/only way to do this ?

Comment: We use autocomplete ourselves (specifically, typeahead.js) and we send out a JSON with the dictionary from a model. We do it because our content is mutable, but now that I think about it I guess you could just render it out from a JSON if it just happens to be huge. I think some people would really question whether your data would change or not though if its huge :) and the whole debate continues...

Comment: Say I want to load this file into a table. How would I do it ? I've tried searching for a tutorial, but can't find any. I'd also have to run this script on the server I'm hosting (heroku)... how does that play out, just run it once from the shell ?

Comment: There are a couple of ways I can think of. You can use [Sprig](https://github.com/vigetlabs/sprig) to create seeds that you will use specifically for production and then `do rake db:seed` in your Heroku environment, which is what we do for this kind of case. It works great as you can store stuff in yml, csv, a bunch of formats. Your second option is to [connect directly with a client](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#external-connections-ingress) and load the data up with SQL. I like the first one better personally :)